# Tokenize a String without spaces using a custom tokenizer in Spacy

Tags: python, tokenize, spacy

I would like to tokenizer some chemical expression called `SMILES`, for example, `[c]1ccc(C(=O)Nc2ccc(Br)cc2)cc1[N+](=O)[O-].C[NH]`. There are no spaces in the string, and after the tokenization, we should get `[c], 1, c, c, c, (, C, (, =, O, ), N, c, 2, c, c, c, (, Br, ), c, c, 2, ), c, c, 1, [N+], (, =, O, ), [O-], ., C, [NH]`, which means some special tokens have more than one character such as `[c]`, `Br` and `[N+]` and they should not be split. Apart from these tokens, other tokens only have one character such as `c`, `(` and `N`. How can I acheive this with a tokenizer from [Spacy](https://spacy.io/)? If spacy is not needed here and only a snippet of python can do this, it would be also acceptable. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the regex for this is quite easy so

```
s = "[c]1ccc(C(=O)Nc2ccc(Br)cc2)cc1[N+](=O)[O-].C[NH]"
tokens = re.findall("\[.+?]|.",s)
```

I guess does what you want

Comment: Thanks, `re.findall("\[.+?]|Br|.",s)` works.